# Styling disabled dijits so only the text appears

Tags: css, dojo

Maybe some of you have experience with styling Dojo dijits. What I'm trying to do is override the right CSS classes so disabled/read only inputs of type textbox, combobox, filtering select show only the text / selected value, without the borders of the element and the greyed out background.

Hopefully someone has an idea of what classes are involved or another idea on how I can achieve this.

Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

I think `dijitDisabled` is the class you're looking for. I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do but I did this quick example with a button. It shows an enabled button and a disabled one in a way that I think is you're looking for. [Here is the running example in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2jADc/).

And here are the individual parts:

HTML:

```
<div id="btn"></div>
<div id="btnDisabled"></div>
```

CSS:

```
@import "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7.2/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css";


.dijitDisabled.dijitButtonDisabled .dijitButtonNode {
    background-image: none;
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
}
```

JS:

```
require(["dijit/form/Button"], function(Button) {
    var button = new Button({ label: "Enabled" },"btn");     
    var buttonDisabled = new Button({ label: "Disabled", disabled: true },"btnDisabled");         
});​
```

​
I assumed dojo 1.7.

I hope it helps,

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, but august was kind of a free month :) 
That is exactly what i was looking for, so for buttons you need to style : .dijitDisabled .dijitButtonDisabled .dijitButtonNode. I was looking for the exact same list for : textboxes (no input border, no background, etc), combobox and filtering select (no input border, no dropdown arrow) and checkboxes (no check).